# How do I make a property dynamic (unknown until the code is executed)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

This is the format of the data I work with:

```
ChecksCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);
ChecksCollection.insert({
  oddsChecked: ['', ''],
  oddsAverages: ['', ''],
  oddsCompeting: ['', ''], 
  ...
```

dynamicProperty could be 'oddsChecked', 'oddsAverages', 'oddsCompeting' and so on. It depends on execution time. How do I make the code from below work?

```
var odds = ChecksCollection.findOne().dynamicProperty[index];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`transform`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) option to create a getter with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
ChecksCollection.findOne({}, {
  transform: doc => Object.defineProperty(doc, 'dynamicProperty', {
    get: function getDynamicProperty() {
      // Your logic here
      // This should return a value (unless you want some obscure
      // side-effecting getter, which no you don't)

      if (this.something) {
        return 42;
      }
      else {
        return 53;
      }
    }
  })
);
```

You can access the object on which the getter is with `this` as long as you don't use an arrow function (which locks `this`).

Comment: Can you please paste some sample logic as well, so that your entire snippet would be functional? I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around it and I've tried using it without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with [`template string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```
var t = ['oddsChecked', 'oddsAverages', 'oddsCompeting'];
var s = t[i]; // the `i` determined at the running time.
var odds = ChecksCollection.findOne({`${s}`: value})...;
```